# how client/server communication works with meteor/nodejs

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm learning about Meteor. Right now I'm trying to figure out how the client/server communication works, I have a file under [root]/server with all the information to connect to DB (user, password, host, port) also I have the following line of code to test this "communication"

```
 var getUsers = function(name) {
           return "Hi. I'm " + name;
      };
```

and in my root folder I have:

```
console.log(getUsers("Juan!"));
```

however I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: getUsers is not defined " error. so the question is, What I'm doing wrong????????

thanks in advance for any help or hint

Answer (score 3):

Discover Meteor book have a great chapter about it:

- Spanish: http://es.discovermeteor.com/chapters/publications-and-subscriptions/
- English: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-meteor-publications-and-subscriptions/

I recommend you read the whole book, is very good.

**Update:**

This point of Meteor refence also explains very well the communication between methods, like server <> client communication.
http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_call